# openApi generator spring template omits default values of properties

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, default-value, openapi-generator, springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin

I attach a basic `OAS 3.0` schema below. When using [editor.swagger.io](https://editor.swagger.io), I am able to view the default values of my properties in generated page, when expanding the schema details.

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: API Specification
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://localhost
paths:
  /operation:
    post:
      operationId: run
      requestBody:
        description: Description
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Request'
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Response'
        '400':
          description: Bad request
        '500':
          description: Internal Server Error
components:
  schemas:
    Request:
      type: object
      properties:
        x:
          type: number
          example: 0
          default: 2
    Response:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
```

[image]

However, when generating the server stubs with the `spring` engine from the top menu of the editor, I notice that the `defaultValue` property of the `@Schema` annotation is not populated.

```java
  // ...
  @JsonProperty("x")
  private BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(2);
  // ...
  /**
   * Get x
   * @return x
   **/
  @Schema(example = "0", description = "")
  
    @Valid
    public BigDecimal getX() {
    return x;
  }
```

As you can see, the generated server class correctly instantiates the default variable.
It's really the property `defaultValue` of the `@Schema` annotation that I am missing. I've seen this property being included in `@Parameter` objects in OAS.
What I would like to see in the above annotation is the additional property as below:

```java
  @Schema(example = "0", description = "", defaultValue="2")
```

Is this a bug of the spring engine template?

I would like to avoid immediately resorting to a custom mustache template if my problem has a known solution with less maintenance.

Comment: Are you using `springdoc-openapi`?

Comment: @MaksimEliseev Yes, I do use the maven springdoc-openapi dependency. However, I believe my problem is before that, since it is the openapi-generator plugin that really omits to produce the server classes with the defaultValue property. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my use-case by bypassing the automatically generated springdoc-openapi file, and directly serving my own original yaml specification. My input
specification file includes all the keywords I need, and they are properly rendered by springdoc's underlying swagger2 implementation.

**Bonus**: I also found out that with the above bypass, I am able to render markdown inside the operation block (the default green colored block of each operation). Sounds corny, but this was liberating and bothered me for a while.

To serve my own yaml, while also having the Try-it-Out button working without throwing those pesky CORS errors, I did the following:

1. Placed my api.yaml file inside the resources/static folder
2. Added the following server property in my application.properties.yaml

```
server:
  forward-headers-strategy: framework
```

3. Modified some springdoc.swagger-ui properties as follows

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    enable: false
    useUnsafeMarkdown: true
    url: api.yaml
    path: /
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
  api-docs:
    enabled: false
    path: /api.yaml
    version: OPENAPI_3_0
```

4. Added the following code in one of my @Configuration annotated classes. Note the use of `@Primary`, which ensures that these beans will be prioritized over other internal beans that do the same. Try to experiment without the annotation, and if it works for you, don't bother adding it. This is what worked for me!

```java
    @Bean
    @Primary
    SpringDocConfiguration springDocConfiguration(){
       return new SpringDocConfiguration();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties() {
       return new SpringDocConfigProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    ObjectMapperProvider objectMapperProvider(SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties){

        return new ObjectMapperProvider(springDocConfigProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    SpringDocUIConfiguration SpringDocUIConfiguration(Optional<SwaggerUiConfigProperties> optionalSwaggerUiConfigProperties){

        return new SpringDocUIConfiguration(optionalSwaggerUiConfigProperties);
    }
```

5. In your yaml specification, set the server url to "/". This may throw a warning by openapi-generator or springdoc, but it actually enabled the proper function of Try-It-Out button, which did not work for me, when serving the api page from the same port as the application. I have no authentication or actuator setup, so this may differ.

PS. [I relied on the springdoc documentation FAQ 13.57 here](https://springdoc.org/#what-is-a-proper-way-to-set-up-swagger-ui-to-use-provided-spec-yml), with some of my own settings to get it to work. I hope it helps someone!

Comment: Is it possible to override swagger-ui.enable: false, programatically rather than relying on properties file?

Comment: @SachinBose I don't know, how to do that, but perhaprs a read of these resources will help you? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties External Configuration in Spring is powerful: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config

Answer (score 1):

**A little investigation on this question**

Actually you have 2 problems in the generated sources:

1. The `@Parameter` annotation in the generated interface wasn't generated quite correctly:

   ```java
   ResponseEntity<Response> run(@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.DEFAULT, description = "Description", required=true, schema=@Schema()) @Valid @RequestBody Request body);
   ```

   As you can see, the `schema` parameter set incorrectly.
2. The `@Schema` annotation in the generated `Request` class, as you described, doesn't have the `defaultValue` parameter:

   ```java
   @Schema(example = "0", description = "")
   @Valid
   public BigDecimal getX() {
       return x;
   }
   ```

I tried the `org.openapi.generator` Gradle plugin (analogue of swagger codegen) and the result was the same:

1. The `schema` parameter in the `@Parameter` annotation wasn't set:

   ```java
   default ResponseEntity<Response> run(
         @Parameter(name = "Request", description = "Description", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody Request request
   ) {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. The same behaviour.

---

In general, the code of the `Request` class is generated correctly: the `x` field is initialized to the default value.

```java
public class Request   {
    @JsonProperty("x")
    private BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(2);

    // ...
}
```

Do you really need proper annotations?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will assign the bounty to you if no other answer provides some other suggestions on how to solve it! Annotations are not a showstopper for me, but right now I can't inform the consumers of my service about the default values of some parameters unless I type it down with text, which may quickly be invalid if I change the defaults and forget to update the text. I know I can use examples instead, but I was hoping it would just work with some configuration I may be missing.

Comment: @Manny, when I worked in a company, we provided generated clients to API consumers. We used swagger-codegen for this. Clients and servers were generated from text (from the Open API specifications), i.e. it was the "text first" approach. I think this makes sense if you are using a "text first" approach. This will force you to remember to update the text and always keep it up to date.

Comment: @Manny, there are two tools: [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) and [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) both have Maven or Gradle plugin for generation servers and clients based on OAS file.

Comment: I may try swagger-codegen in this case, Thank you for the alternative option! Less maintenance is better!